# OCES3 authentication p12 cert API request

Tags: java, rest, authentication

I'm trying to connect the a Danish authority resource

Error

> OpenSSL SSL_read: OpenSSL/3.0.11: error:0A00045C:SSL routines::tlsv13
> alert certificate required, errno 0

Docs:
https://rep.erst.dk/git/openebusiness/common/-/blob/master/guidelines/api/pors-openapi-docs.json

In the docs i the top right corner when you press "Authorize" it looks like there are two options

- x-client-cert (apiKey)
- bearer-token  (http, Bearer)

I have a OCES3 (MitID) system cert (.p12 file) and this is how I extract the public cert (is this the correct way?)

```
openssl pkcs12 -in ean.p12 -clcerts -nokeys -out public_cert.pem
```

Which option should I use to connect to the API?

## update

When I'm trying the first option `x-client-cert (apiKey)`

I use `openssl pkcs12 -in ean.p12 -clcerts -nokeys -out public_cert.pem` to extract the cert from `.p12` file

Then I copy/paste the cert `public_cert.pem` (the output file from the above command)

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
[copy this text]
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Then I remove all newlines so the string is in one line and put it in the header `x-client-cert`

```
*   Trying 87.63.97.27:443...
* Connected to registrationservice-demo.nemhandel.dk (87.63.97.27) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN: offers h2,http/1.1
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN: server did not agree on a protocol. Uses default.
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=DK; ST=Copenhagen; L=Copenhagen; O=Erhvervsstyrelsen; CN=*.nemhandel.dk
*  start date: Aug  1 11:41:05 2023 GMT
*  expire date: Sep  1 11:41:04 2024 GMT
*  issuer: C=BE; O=GlobalSign nv-sa; CN=GlobalSign RSA OV SSL CA 2018
*  SSL certificate verify result: unable to get local issuer certificate (20), continuing anyway.
* using HTTP/1.x
> GET /nemhandelpors/rest/ HTTP/1.1
Host: registrationservice-demo.nemhandel.dk
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: application/json
x-client-cert: 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

* OpenSSL SSL_read: OpenSSL/3.0.11: error:0A00045C:SSL routines::tlsv13 alert certificate required, errno 0
* Closing connection 0
```